# How can I save the second word of each line of a file into a char?

Tags: c

I've got a file called "server.cfg" with this content:

```
NAME SRV-01
MAC 000543D3F4D8
```

I want to save "SRV-01" and "000543D3F4D8" to 2 char*.
I did something like this:

```
FILE *fileS;
char *name;
char *mac;
char *p;

fileS=fopen("server.cfg","r");
while(fgets(line,1000,fileS)!=NULL){
    if(line[0]=="N"){
        p=strtok(line," ");
        p=strtok(NULL," ");
        name=p;
        printf("Name: %s\n",name);
    }
    if(line[0]=="M"){
        p=strtok(line," ");
        p=strtok(NULL," ");
        mac=p;
        printf("Name: %s Mac: %s\n",name,mac);
    }
```

The output is:

```
Name: SRV-01
Name: 000543D3F4D8 Mac: 000543D3F4D8
```

But I would want this output:

```
Name: SRV-01
Name: SRV-01 Mac: 000543D3F4D8
```

I know that the problem is related to the pointers, but I don't know how could I solve it. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must work with the memory management; [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) returns a pointer into the input string (`line`), which of course will be replaced by each successive `fgets()`.

If you have it, you can use [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to duplicate the string and store that, or just use arrays rather than pointers and `strcpy()` the text in.

Also, since you can be pretty sure that your line won't start with *both* `'n'` and `'m'`, the second `if` should be an `else if`. Your handling of upper/lower case there seems dubious, too (`'n`' doesn't equal `'N'`).